# MeSH (Medical Subjects Heading) Dataset (mesh.nt) not working in RDFLib Python

Tags: python, rdflib, n-triples

I am trying to figure out the loading time, traversal time, and queries response time of RDFLib using MeSH dataset in N-Triple format.

I am trying to execute the queries for two days but no luck.

Here is the code:

```
import time
from rdflib import ConjunctiveGraph
def mem_func():
query1="""
    PREFIX rdf: http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#
    PREFIX rdfs: http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#
    PREFIX xsd: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#
    PREFIX owl: http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#
    PREFIX meshv: http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/vocab#
    PREFIX mesh: http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/
    PREFIX mesh2015: http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/2015/
    PREFIX mesh2016: http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/2016/
    PREFIX mesh2017: http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/2017/

     SELECT ?d ?dName ?c ?cName
     FROM <http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh>
     
     WHERE {
       
     ?d a meshv:Descriptor .
     ?d meshv:active 1 .
     ?d meshv:concept ?c .
     ?d rdfs:label ?dName .
     ?c rdfs:label ?cName
     FILTER(REGEX(?dName,"infection","i") || REGEX(?cName,"infection","i"))
     
     }
     ORDER BY ?d
    """
g = ConjunctiveGraph()

print("RDFlib DS-2 Loading Started:")
start_time = time.time()

g.parse("mesh.nt", format="nt")
print("RDFlib DS-2 Loading Finished:")

print("--- Loading Time approx %s ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
print("RDF DS-2 Traversal Time Started ")

start_time_traversal = time.time()
file1 = open('mesh.nt','r')
Lines = file1.readlines()

for line in Lines:
    print(line.strip())

print("RDF DS-2 Traversal Time Finished ")
print("--- Traversal Time approx %s ---" % (time.time() - start_time_traversal))

results = g.query(query1)

for row in results:
     print(row)

if name == "main":
mem_func()
```

When my program hits the line where the query executes it is throwing an exception:

```
https://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/!DOCTYPE html does not look like a valid URI, trying to serialize this will break.
        https://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/html lang="en" does not look like a valid URI, trying to serialize this 
        will break.
        Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-
        packages\rdflib\plugins\parsers\ntriples.py", line 154, in parse
        self.parseline()
        File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site- 
        packages\rdflib\plugins\parsers\ntriples.py", line 197, in parseline
        subject = self.subject()
        File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site- 
        packages\rdflib\plugins\parsers\ntriples.py", line 224, in subject
        subj = self.uriref() or self.nodeid()
        File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site- 
        packages\rdflib\plugins\parsers\ntriples.py", line 243, in uriref
        uri = self.eat(r_uriref).group(1)
        File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site- 
        packages\rdflib\plugins\parsers\ntriples.py", line 218, in eat
        raise ParseError("Failed to eat %s at %s" % (pattern.pattern, self.line))
        rdflib.plugins.parsers.ntriples.ParseError: Failed to eat <([^:]+:[^\s"<>]*)> at
       
        During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
       
        Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site- 
        packages\rdflib\plugins\sparql\sparql.py", line 285, in _load
        return graph.load(source, format='nt', **kwargs)
        File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site- 
        packages\rdflib\graph.py", line 1085, in load
        self.parse(source, publicID, format)
        File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site- 
        packages\rdflib\graph.py", line 1549, in parse
        context.parse(source, publicID=publicID, format=format, **args)
        File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site- 
        packages\rdflib\graph.py", line 1078, in parse
        parser.parse(source, self, **args)
        File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site- 
        packages\rdflib\plugins\parsers\nt.py", line 26, in parse
        parser.parse(f)
        File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site- 
        packages\rdflib\plugins\parsers\ntriples.py", line 156, in parse
        raise ParseError("Invalid line: %r" % self.line)
        rdflib.plugins.parsers.ntriples.ParseError: Invalid line: ''
       
        During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
       
        Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "E:\ToP_RDF_research\rdflib_python_eclipse\src\pyRDF_D2.py", line 135, in
        mem_func()
        File "E:\ToP_RDF_research\rdflib_python_eclipse\src\pyRDF_D2.py", line 107, in mem_func
        results = g.query(query1)
        File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site- 
        packages\rdflib\graph.py", line 1131, in query
        return result(processor.query(query_object, initBindings, initNs, **kwargs))
        File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site- 
        packages\rdflib\plugins\sparql\processor.py", line 80, in query
        return evalQuery(self.graph, query, initBindings, base)
        File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site- 
        packages\rdflib\plugins\sparql\evaluate.py", line 526, in evalQuery
        ctx.load(d.default, default=True)
        File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site- 
        packages\rdflib\plugins\sparql\sparql.py", line 299, in load
        _load(self.graph, source)
        File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site- 
        packages\rdflib\plugins\sparql\sparql.py", line 289, in _load
        source))
        Exception: Could not load http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh as either RDF/XML, N3 or NTriples
```

So far, I only figure out that it takes approximately 3hrs loading time and 14 min traversal time.

Where am I going wrong, and how would I be able to run this successfully?

Comment: `FROM <http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh>` does not look like valid SQL syntax at all. The argument after `FROM` should be a table name. The error traceback looks like it's pulling in the actual HTML source of something and trying to consume that as URLs, but maybe that's a secondary effect of the FROM error. (Not familiar with RDFlib so maybe I'm just displaying my ignorance here.)

Comment: @triplee, that is not SQL.

Comment: yes it is not SQL, it is SPARQL used for RDF Query